# does not work height: 100vh; when using @average

Tags: css

I am not able to make height: 100vh work; when the window has a resolution lower than 1000px, follow the code. I tried several ways to make it work, but I can't

```css
@media (max-width: 1400px){
   #child{
      height: 100vh; /* does not work */
   } 
}

#father {
   z-index: 2;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: red;
   text-align: center;
}

#child{
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   margin: 20px auto;
   padding: 10px;
   width: 60%;
   height: 30%;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="father">
    <div id="child">test
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `#child` is defined after the `@media` rule. Your selector does not override the existing property correctly. I'd not use IDs for styling either - they just make it more complicated to override styles due to specificity.

See also here: [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/how-much-specificity-do-rules-have-like-keyframes-and-media/)

```css
#father {
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

#child {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 1400px) {
  #child {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="father">
  <div id="child">test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Got it, I didn't know you could use @media at the bottom of the css, I thought you could only always use it at the top, in the first lines of the css.
When using id it was just to exemplify the error in question, thanks for the reply.